# ILNumerics: compund test for ILLogical: AND two logical conditions

Tags: ilnumerics

I am trying to create an ILLogical array that selects data between upper and lower limits like this:

*ILLogical ix = a > limit[0] & a < limit[1]*

where a and limit are ILArray< double >. I get an ILArgumentException about "Nonscalar logical to bool conversion" asking me to see ILSettings.LogicalArrayToBoolConversion. Changing the '&' to '&&' doesn't help. Is there no way to set up a compound test resulting in an ILLogical? What are my alternatives?

Comment: I guess one way is to combine the tests into a single test: ix = (a - limit[0]) * (limit[1] - a) > 0

Answer (score 1):

There is no (convenient) way to overload the binary logical operators as `&` in C# in the way required here. Also, if such way would exist it would badly act against common intuition and likely cause more confusion than convenience.

Instead use the functional interface with `ILMath.and()` & Co:

```
 ILLogical ix = ILMath.and(a > limit[0], a < limit[1]);
```

See: [API class documentation on `and`](https://ilnumerics.net/apidoc/?topic=html/M_ILNumerics_ILMath_and_3.htm)

Comment: I actually had already tried that and got the same error. That's what led me to the solution I added as a comment to my first post.

Comment: I think the reason 'and' failed for me was that I was using the C# bindings at https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire-dotnet which didn't bind it. Once I added that binding 'and' did work.

Comment: From the [online docu](http://ilnumerics.net/Opoverload.html): _The C# operators | (bitwise or) and & (bitwise and) are not applicable to ILArray<T>. Overriding them would conflict with the || operator which is used for combining ILLogical arrays and considered more important._